# Calculating Age: Ambiguous reference to member on DateComponents

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to come up with a code that calculates age from a datePicker allocated to a text field. I get the correct date just fine, it passed the print test. However, while trying to get dateComponents to work I get the "Ambiguous reference to member 'dateComponents(_:from:to:)'"error. -- This is not the same code as the one stackoverflow notified me of, I am trying to use datepicker to get there. --

I looked around for solutions online and I can't seem to get past this. Can you help please?

-Total Beginner

```
@objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {

    let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let dmy = myCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    inputTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    let birthdayDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    print(birthdayDate)

    let now = NSDate()
    let ageComponents = myCalendar.dateComponents(.year, from: birthdayDate, to: now) //Ambiguous reference to member 'dateComponents(_:from:to:)'
    let age = ageComponents.year!

    label.text = age

    view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: Use `Date()`, not `NSDate()`

Comment: `label.text = age`  should be `label.text = String(age)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code

1. You should use `Date`, not `NSDate` in Swift
2. `birthdayDate` is a `String`, but the `from:` parameter needs to be an instance of `Date`
3. The components parameter needs to be a set.

Correcting these gives you:

```
@objc func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {

    let birthdayDate = datePicker.date
    let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let dmy = myCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    inputTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: birthdayDate)

    let now = Date()
    let ageComponents = myCalendar.dateComponents([.year], from: birthdayDate, to: now)
    let age = ageComponents.year!

    label.text = "\(age)"

    view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: You can't assign an `Int` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
let ageComponents = myCalendar.dateComponents(.year, from: birthdayDate, to: now)
```

You are directly passing `.year` to `dateComponents`, but it actually expects a `Set<DateComponents>`. Also, `birthdayDate` is a `String`, not a `Date`. You should pass `datePicker.date` instead. So you should do this:

```
let ageComponents = myCalendar.dateComponents([.year], from: datePicker.date, to: now)
```

Also, `now` should be a `Date`, not `NSDate`.

Comment: It is definitely better to use `Calendar` than multiply seconds, since that won't account for leap years or leap seconds. although the error probably isn't significant over a normal lifespan, it is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Stackoverflow is awesome! I hadn't even think of leap years when I thought about that.